# Exiting a procedure

Tags: console-application, freepascal

I have some very simple code, but I cannot figure this out. I'm calling a procedure that will (hopefully) exit the process. But it doesn't exactly do that:

```
procedure quit;
begin
    exit;
end;
```

And here's where i'm calling it:

`If (Ch2 = #13) and (Bar2 = 5) and (Five) Then Quit;`

`Bar2` is basically a byte variable that holds an array with different elements, like `"display"`, `"help"`, `"next"` and `"prev"`, and of course, `quit`, Which all have their own code based on what they do.
`Ch2` is a variable for `ReadKey` that takes in various key presses, and then allows it to do whatever is defined for that specfic command. In this case, it requires that the return key is used.
`Five` is a boolean operator, and is there as a prerequisite to run the `quit` command. I guess it isn't really necessary.

BTW, if it helps, this is a unit, not a standalone program.

Anyone know why this `exit` command isn't working? Hopefully this post is verbose enough.

Thank you.

Comment: Your description is rather imprecise. Byte values can't hold arrays, they can at most hold an index into an array. Your Five variable *may or may not be necessary*? You don't know? You say this is a unit, not a standalone program, so what you call a "process" is probably not really one. Please work on your terminology, so people can actually understand what you are really doing. And give some more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`exit`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/exit.html) statement exits from the function or procedure in which it is found. It then returns execution to the calling function or procedure.

To terminate the process use [`halt`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/halt.html).

Comment: Yeah, I tried halt. It exits the entire program, and not just the process.

Comment: The process and the program are the same thing. If you disagree, then you need to clarify what distinction you draw.

Comment: The main pogram is a BBS, which is the parent of the process i'm trying to exit from. When I use `halt`, it exits the entire BBS. The unit which I speak of is the child process. I should of clarified that in my original post.

Comment: `halt` will terminate the process in which it is executed. It will not terminate a parent process. This is stated in the documentation to which I linked, and that I do hope you read. Which says: *Halt stops program execution and returns control to the calling program*. Did you read this?

Comment: Ok. Understood. How would one terminate a child process?

Comment: Execute `halt` inside the child process would be one way. There might be others depending on how the child process was started. Most of that detail hidden from us, and we have long since strayed from the question that you asked, which I believe has been answered.

Comment: 1) I run the BBS. 2) I execute the child routine. 3) I initiate the `halt` command. 4) The BBS is terminated. I need to figure out a way to terminate the child process. Which is why I think I need to use the `exit` command. Maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. I answered the question you asked. We can't be expected to debug programs we cannot see. Now that you know what these two programs do, it's time for you to go to work.

Comment: My original question has been answered, yes, but it has brought up an entirely new question. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @user2411434: What you call a process and what a process really is might differ. If you execute halt and the entire BBS is stopped, then the "process" you are referring to and the BBS are (part of) the same process actually. What you call process is probably just a subroutine.

Comment: Ahh. Yes. Well, I did figure it out. And the solution was `exit`, not `halt` `    `#13 : if (Bar2 = 5) and (Five) then exit;`

Comment: As @DavidHeffernan said, to exit from a *process*, you use `Halt`. To exit from a procedure or function, you use `Exit`. So, if `Exit` works for you, you are ***not*** exiting from a process, as I assumed already.

Comment: @user2411434: Also note that the Exit in your Quit procedure only exits from Quit itself. Exit can not exit from an outer procedure or from a calling procedure or function.